# Why was Vidura silent on Lakshagraha?

Tags: mahabharata, vidura

Vidura already know about [Lakshagraha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshagraha#Plot) before Pandavas go varnavat.

He also warns the pandvas with different Mleccha language. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshagraha#Plot):

> "A weapon not made of steel or any other material element can be more than sharp to kill an enemy, and he who knows this is never killed."
>
> Fire cannot extinguish the soul but can annihilate the material body.
>   But one who protects the soul lives.
>
> The conflagration that devastates a forest cannot hurt a rat which shelters itself in a hole or a porcupine which burrows in the earth. The wise man knows his bearings by looking at the stars.

So why he keep silent and don't talk to anyone about this thing, if he do something and stop Pandavas to go Lakshagraha, then pandvas will never go to there and Yudhishthira will still remain as Yuvraj, OK may be Shakuni and Yudhisthar does not give him a chance to speak and hence he said in different language.

But why does he keep silent When King Dhutrashtra, Bhisma, Sage Drona and Sage Krupacharya make Duryodhana as Yuvraj. OK now your answer is may be he is not there.

But why does he keep silent on Pandavas dies as well, if Pandavas go back to Hastinapur, then Yudhishthira will remain Yuvraj again.

My main question: Was Vidura not aware that if Duryodhana become Yuvraj then whole thing become more complex later, why does he remain silent and does not talk about that thing to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vidura helped PAndava at every chance.

> The wicked Duryodhana, beholding Bhimasena surpass (everybody) in strength and Arjuna highly accomplished in arms became pensive and sad. Then Karna, the offspring of the Sun, and Sakuni, the son of Suvala, endeavoured by various means to compass the death of the Pandavas. **The Pandavas too counteracted all those contrivances one after another, and in obedience to the counsels of Vidura, never spoke of them afterwards**.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01144.htm)

We can very well derive the then dynamics of the palace politics. The reason for keeping quiet can be many:

- Vidura may loose his post, had he openly condemn those techniques; Then no secret saviour of PAndava-s
- Even had he condemned openly, that would have brought infamy to the whole Kuru race (including PAndava), because such things spread quickly among the citizens, which would reduce the trust towards their rulers
- Vidura was aware of Dhritarashtra sanctioning the wicked plan of burning them alive; Being an obedient minister, he couldn't openly oppose his own elder brother

  > Then the son of Suvala (Sakuni), king Duryodhana, Duhsasana and Kama, in consultation with one another, formed an evil conspiracy. With the sanction of Dhritarashtra, the king of the Kurus, they resolved to burn to death Kunti and her (five) sons.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01144.htm)
- Vidura was not a real threat to Duryodhana & co.. This is how the plan of "Varnavrata" itself got materialise

  > Duryodhana answered, '... Kshattri (Vidura) is dependent on us for his means of life, though he is secretly with the foe. It he sides the Pandavas, he alone can do us no injury, Therefore, exile thou the Pandavas to Varanavata (place of house of lac) without any fear.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01145.htm)

---

Nevertheless, **Vidura didn't remain silent towards Kunti; He informed them about the treachery & also helped by letting Kunti & sons escape, beforehand**. He just kept mum towards DhritarAshtra & sons, as there was no use of preaching them when they were devoid of morality already.

Here how the story of *LAkshyagruha @ Varnavrata* happened in very brief:

> Then the sinless **Vidura**, of soul enlightened by true knowledge, and **devoted to the good of the Pandavas**, came to the conclusion that Kunti with her children should fly away from her foes. And providing for that purpose a boat strong enough to withstand both wind and wave, he addressed Kunti and **said, 'This Dhritarashtra hath been born for destroying the fame and offspring of the (Kuru) race. Of wicked soul, he is about to cast off eternal virtue. O blessed one, I have kept ready on the stream a boat capable of withstanding both wind and wave. Escape by it with thy children from the net that death hath spread around you.'**
>   Kunti was deeply grieved, and with her children, O bull of Bharata's race, stepped into the boat and went over the Ganges. **Then leaving the boat according to the advice of Vidura, the Pandavas took with them the wealth that had been given to them (while at Varanavata) by their enemies and safely entered the deep woods.** In the house of lac, however, that had been prepared for the destruction of the Pandavas, an innocent Nishada woman who had come there for some purpose, was, with her children burnt to death. And that worst of Mlechchhas, the wretched Purochana (who was the architect employed in building the house of lac) was also burnt in the conflagration. And thus were the sons of Dhirtarashtra with their counsellors deceived in their expectations. And thus also were the illustrious Pandavas, by the advice of Vidura, saved with their mother.

As you see, the help from Vidura here was quite explicit. It was merely a lucky coincidence for him that Duryodhana etc. got deceived due to circumstances. Else upon inquiry, Duryodhana might have found out some insider's help in escaping of PAndava-s.

---

The language used by Vidura to Yudhishtira can be found in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01148.htm). Due to it's length, I am just putting its meaning:

> Kunti approached Yudhishthira and said, 'The words that Kshattri said unto thee in the midst of many people so indistinctly as if he did not say anything, and thy reply also to him in similar words and voice, we have not understood. ... Yudhishthira replied, 'The virtuous Vidura said unto me that we should know that the mansion (for our accommodation at Varanavata) hath been built of inflammable materials. He said unto me, 'The path of escape too shall not be unknown to thee,'--and further,--'Those that can control their senses can acquire the sovereignty of the whole world.'

Comment: "With the sanction of Dhritarashtra, the king of the Kurus, they resolved to burn to death Kunti and her (five) sons" As far I know Dhritarashtra not aware fully about lakshagraha, he just fulfill his son request, he know that there is some mystery but he does not know that shakuni and duryodhan try to make plan to kill kunti and her five sons. If he know whole plan, then he will refuse it, and hence shakuni said, go to your father and said pandvas should take some rest on varnvat(On festival of lord shiva) because they have conquered on many kings.

Comment: @Goyllo, yes that's how it was also portrayed in BRC Mahabharata, which was more charitable towards the character of Dhritarashtra who was seen as a rather anti-hero than a villain. TV serials may take little creative liberty. However, what I have pasted is from the authentic source of Mahabharata, which wouldn't be deviated [much] from the original story. So in such case you may consider that Vidura was aware of Dhritarashtra's approvals towards this wrongdoings; due to which he can't oppose openly.

Comment: Dhritarashtra once resigned vidura, but due to anger of bhisma he request vidura to get back for hastinapur, also vidura does not care about his post, he always spoke bitter truth even King like it or not. I agree with your second point, if citizen know about that, then revolt will happen and that is not good for hastinapur. and for hastinapur vidura can do anything. OK I got my answer :)  Yes it's authenticate source then BRC Mahabharata, so I think I need to do more study on that :) Thank you :)